# Term to identify siblings - one dutiful, one rebellious towards their parents

Tags: single-word-requests

In a story, one person has two sons. One of them loves his parents and other hates his parents and beats them.  In Hindi, the person who cares for his parents is called "Sapoot" and the person who beats his parents is called "Kapoot."

Are there equivalent terms in English?

Comment: I don't think there are words for these, though it reminds me of [the parable of the Prodigal Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prodigal_Son). I note by the way that "take remand of him" is meaningless in my (British) English - I had to read the question to understand what you meant by it.

Comment: I agree with all of @ColinFine's points, adding I can't think of a single word for such a pair of people, other than stating they are very different/contrasting to one another.

Comment: Hi! Friends  in Hindi language, the person who cares to his parents is called "Sapoot" and the person who beats to his parents is called "Kapoot". and the story is written in Hindi language. there should be a specific word for those person in English language .

Comment: Brothers with opposite personalities!

Comment: Why _should_ there be a "word" in English to accurately describe every single character in every single story written in every single language in the world?

Comment: @oerkelens is right, there are some concepts and words in languages that just don't translate, or don't translate well, to others.

Comment: The British have 1000 words for rain. Or is it for Eskimos? Anyway, wouldn't we say 'good son' and 'bad son'? (The Prodigal's brother was not exactly a good son. It's the Father who impresses me.)

Comment: You can always use "evil twin" vs. "good twin" as a metaphor.

Comment: This is probably not the perfect site for this question because you might have to turn to literature to get parallel characters that might be widely known to a particular culture.

Answer (score 1):

There was a continuing series in Highlights magazine (well represented in dentist offices) called **"Goofus and Gallant"** about the "Bad Boy" Goofus who did bad things and the contrasting good kid Gallant.

It is not an exact fit and applies to more situations, but might at least give AmE readers an idea of where you are going.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob and Esau. Esau also had hairy hands (se other post)